# Android youtube app layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi guys I need to develop an app for android platform. I would like to use a layout as youtube app has. I mean that button from the left top corner when I tap it to open another view but not on full screen. I look on internet but I couldn't find anything useful. Can you share with me some useful documentation about this type of layout?

Comment: have you tried searching ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Gui sliding sidebar](https://github.com/walkingice/gui-sliding-sidebar/) or [Android sliding menu](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo)

Also, look at the [Android UI patterns](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ncm9pZGlmeS51aXBhdHRlcm5zIl0.) from Google play market. It's very useful app!